# Update view after form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, form-submit

In my MVC controller I have two action methods.

The first one is Index method:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return PopulateViewModel();
    }
```

The "PopulateViewModel" Action Method is used for updating of the view model and then showing these updated values on the Index view.

```
public IActionResult PopulateViewModel()
    {
        ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel()
        {
           //updating values in the view model
           //the values are received when the form in the view is submitted
        };

        return View("Index", viewModel);
    }
```

The problem that I have is that on my Index view the updated values are not shown immediately after submitting the form in the view. When I submit the form I must then once again refresh the page to see the updated values.

What could be the reason for such behavior and how can I correct that?

Comment: Are you submitting to the `Index()` action method you shared in your question ? It does not have any parameters
`

Comment: `Index()` should surely be a `[HttpPost]` method and be receiving the submitted values from the form as a parameter? Or else how are you reading them? Take the introductory tutorial from Microsoft, it'll show you how to bind your viewmodel object to the submitted values from your form

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the conceptual notion.  The index is supposed to represent the initial page state.  Other actions within the controller will modify the output by rendering the page with the adjusted model.  Or handling server side model binding, but the concept is fundamentally achieving the same result.

Your controller logic should be within the following constraints.

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
     public IActionResult Index() => new View("...", ...);

     public IActionResult SubmitSample(string location)
     {
          var model = service.GetLabLocations(location);
          return View("...", model);
     }
}
```

The index is simulating a `GET` request, returning the initial page in the required state.  The form portion, should `POST` data, outlined in the `SubmitSample` portion of the code.  This will change the state of the page, but the server will need to render with those changes.  So the page will load with the attached model, for you to display.

This would represent Razor more than likely on the server side.

```
@if(Model != null)
     foreach(var sample in Model)
     {
          // Markup, with the data
     }
```